# Publish NuGet package using BUILD_ID

Tags: jenkins, nuget, jenkins-plugins

I cannot use the build_id in command line. Any suggestion for step 3?

1.) nuget pack test.nuspec -Version 1.0.%BUILD_ID%

2.) test.1.0.1.nupkg

3.) Publish the package, ERROR: Step ‘Publish NuGet packages’ failed: No packages were published.

[image]

Comment: solved : test.1.0.$BUILD_ID.nupkg

Answer (score 0):

The $ solved my problem. I did check the jenkins code.

[image]